# Angular2 RegExp escape space

Tags: regex

I am learning Angular2 and I would like to validate input by custom RegExp.

`^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$`

`var exp = ^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$`

For example: Given an input that contains special characters:

`¡™¢∞§¶•ªº∆œ∑´®†¥ˆ¨ßç¬ç∫∂´ƒ®øƒ˚√∆∑´∂˜œøç∆®©ƒ…©˙π´∑˜çµ∑∂ßå≈≈`

I want to validate this input using given regular expression

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match ?

Comment: @Rahul Given an input, i would like to validate that input matching this regular expression.

Comment: Yes but what's the pattern ? Give some valid examples.

Comment: Regex has a whitespace class: `\s`. If that doesn't work, please give some examples of what you're trying to match and where your expression is failing, with a [mcve]. I find https://regex101.com/ useful when I'm trying to write a regex.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am working with LoL API and this RegExp is given in their documentation for validating input.

Comment: That's fine, but doesn't address any of what I said: please [edit] the question to provide more information than *"facing problems"*.

Comment: It's a typo, simple typo questions are off-topic on so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using literal syntax, then you should change this:

```
var exp = ^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$
```

to:

```
var exp = /^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$/;
//        ^                   ^
```

Or, you can use constructor syntax:

```
var exp = new RegExp('^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$');
```

See [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thanks! That is what i wanted